# Dataproc job logs not available from dataproc.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, google-cloud-dataproc

I have the following policies enabled in a dataproc cluster

```
  **"dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable": "true",
    "dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable": "true",
    "dataproc:dataproc.monitoring.stackdriver.enable": "true",**
    "dataproc:efm.mapreduce.shuffle": "hcfs",
    "dataproc:efm.spark.shuffle": "primary-worker",
    "dataproc:job.history.to-gcs.enabled": "true",
    **"dataproc:yarn.log-aggregation.enabled": "true"**
```

But I dont get the job logs from the dataproc.googleapis.com. But I get the yarn logs. Please let me know if its possible to get the job logs from the dataproc API as well as from the yarn logs. Thanks.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-job-output

Comment: Have you tried viewing it at Cloud Logging?  You can specify the parameters like job id, resources etc etc : https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/logging#access_job_logs_in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the parameters shown in the question are enabled it is possible to get both dataproc logs as well as yarn logs.